# Are there any complete orthogonal basis functions inside unit sphere?

Tags: orthonormal, spherical-geometry, orthogonal-polynomials, complete-spaces, spherical-harmonics

I went through so much literature, but couldn't find any orthogonal complete functions within the boundary

$0 < r <1, 0 < \theta <\pi, 0 < \phi <2\pi$

other than 3D Zernike Polynomials. Can any one let me know such a set of functions, if there are any, or that there isn't?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Choose different weight functions, you will get different basis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But wouldn't the orthogonality condition be violated when we change the weight functions.